# Echo an array value

Tags: php, arrays, echo

I have a Joomla widget to make and I made a php script that gets the latest articles. The images of all articles are inside the *introtext* value in this way:
bla bla bla  bla bla

I have made the following code to get the images src value:

```
    $variable = $row['introtext'];
    preg_match_all('/(src)=[^ ]+(\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)/',$variable, $out);
    print_r($out[0]);
    echo "http://mysiteurl.com/".$out[0]." ";
```

What I get printed when I hit the file is:

```
Array ( [0] => src="images/DECEMBER2014/ello-vs-facebook.jpg ) http://mysiteurl.com/Array
```

Should not $out[0] echo this:
src="images/DECEMBER2014/ello-vs-facebook.jpg

Any help?

Comment: When you use `preg_match_all`, `$out` is a 2-dimensional array. So `$out[0]` is an array of all the mastches. You can't echo an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$variable = $row['introtext'];
preg_match_all('/(src)=[^ ]+(\.gif|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png)/',$variable, $out);
print_r($out[0][0]);
echo "http://mysiteurl.com/".$out[0][0]." ";
```

Read more about `preg_match_all` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

Answer (score 0):

**Are you looking for this...**

```
foreach($variable as $key=>$value)
{

}
```